# What are the werewolves in the Bartimaeus series?

Tags: werewolf, bartimaeus

In the Bartimaeus series, it seems that all magical powers come ultimately from demons/spirits (the inhabitants of the Other Place) and magicians' ability to enslave them and/or harness their powers. Even magical objects with no obvious demonic component, like the Amulet of Samarkand or an elemental sphere or Gladstone's Staff, contain demons within them that create their power.

In that case, what on earth is going on with the werewolves of the Night Police? They're definitely human and not from the Other Place - Henry Duvall is one of them - but they have powers to change from man to wolf and back, plus at times an inhuman bloodlust. Is this the only example in the series of supernatural powers that don't require demonic involvement, and if so, how *do* they get those powers? Or *is* there a demon involved somehow in the process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *The Golem's Eye* we read

> The scene below was one of chaos. Wounded creatures lay here and there across the street amid
> piles of broken brick and glass. They writhed and growled and clutched their flanks, their contours
> altering with each spasm. Man, wolf, man, wolf... That's the problem with lycanthropy: it's so hard
> to control. Pain and strong emotion make the body shift.[1]
>
> [1] This chronic unreliability is one of the reasons werewolves get such bad press. As is the fact that
> they're ravenous, savage, bloodthirsty, and very poorly house-trained. Lycaon of Arcadia assembled
> the first wolf corps as his personal bodyguard, way back about 2000 B.C., and despite the fact that
> they promptly ate several of his houseguests, the notion of their fulfilling a useful enforcing role
> stuck fast. Many tyrannical rulers who had recourse to magic have used them ever since: casting
> complex transformation spells over suitably brawny humans, keeping them in isolation, and
> sometimes carrying out breeding programs to improve the strain. As with so much else, it was
> Gladstone who inaugurated the British Night Police; he knew their worth as instruments of fear.

as narrated by Bartimaeus. Therefore, lycanthropy involves casting transformation spells on humans - and presumably the demons/spirits are the ones who must be casting those initial spells (since, as you say, all magic ultimately derives from them).